# A function of two functions that loses dependence on an argument

Tags: mathematica

Say I have two functions:

```
f[a_,b_]:=a + b
g[c_,d_,e_]:=c + d - e
```

And I define a third function:

```
h[u_,v_,w_,x_]:=f[u,v]+g[w,x,u]
```

It's clear (to me, a human, at least) that `h` doesn't depend on `u`, but Mathematica still requires this extra argument to define `h` without trickery. This is a simple situation where I could replace the occurrences of `u` with something non-divergent, like 1. But for more complicated cases, such a choice could lead to unwanted (and essentially artificial) divergences. Is there a `Correct Way (TM)` to do this kind of functional definition, or is the general case really impossible for a CAS like Mathematica?

Comment: Formally, $h$ does require $u$, as the product on the right hand side is undefined when $u=0$.

Comment: Craig: see edit, my case here is really an addition of sorts, so no undefined things pop up.

Comment: Thanks for the Accept.  I see you did not upvote my answer however.  If it is lacking, please tell me why, and consider un-Accpting it, since then the question is not resolved.  Otherwise, please vote for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define your function using `Set` rather than `SetDelayed` and use `Simplify` or `FullSimplify` to cancel what Mathematica automatically can.  I use `Module` to avoid collisions with global symbols.

```
f[a_, b_] := a + b
g[c_, d_, e_] := c + d - e

Module[{u, v, w, x},
  h[v_, w_, x_] = f[u, v] + g[w, x, u] // Simplify
]
```

Now the definition of `h` reads:

```
h[v$_, w$_, x$_] = v$ + w$ + x$
```